# NSTableview set selectionHighlightStyle to NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone programmatically in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstableview, nstablerowview

If I selected a row, I want to disable the highlighting blue color. In Swift language, I'm unable to set selectionHighlightStyle to NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone for my NSTableview.

This is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    let cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView

    tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone // error statement "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone'"

    return cellView
}
```

For the statement `tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` it is throwing an error 'Use of unresolved identifier 'NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone'.

Comment: try this cell?.selectionStyle = .None

Comment: I have tried. It is throwing an error 'Value of type 'NsTableCellView' has no member 'SelectionStyle''

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        let cellView: NSTableCellView = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier(tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as! NSTableCellView
        
        cellView.selectionStyle = .None
        
    }

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35173178/edit) your question with the new information instead of pasting it in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @EricD. I have edited my question, please check and help me to resolve the issue I'm facing. Thanks

Comment: is there a strong reason why you have to do this programatically ? If no, disable the highlight in the storyboard. If yes, maybe you can just disable the row selection at all ?

Comment: @Lubos I have added NSTableview programmatically and I have action to do after row selection. And now I'm struck with this issue.

Comment: @PrashanthRajagopalan - NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone doesn't compile in Swift, because you have to use only .None. I cannot test it right now, but I think this is the case. Try:  tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .None

Comment: @Lubos Awesome. It works. Please write it as answer. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your code as following to make it compilable in Swift:

```
tableView.selectionHighlightStyle = .None
```